# Why do indices result in so much unused disk space?

Tags: sql-server, database

I am working with an rather big MS SQL Database of ~8 TB. As the disk is running full I wanted to investigate if there is any elegant way to reduce the size of the database with out deleting data.
When I take a look into the Disk Usage Report in *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio* (image can be seen below) and it appears that a huge amount of disk space is currently unused.

[image]

When I take a look at the Disk *Usage by Partition*  report it seems that the *Non-Clustered Indexes* are the problems. E.g. one index has ~5 TB of “Reserved” space but only uses ~1,7TB.
Regarding this I have got a few questions:

1. What is the unused space which is mentioned in the reports? Do I assume correctly that it is space to which the indexes point which is still empty?
2. Is there anything I can do about these indexes having such a bad ration from unused to used Disk space? (Without losing the advantage of the indexes of course). But two parts unused space to one part used space seems rather bad.
3. A college of mine advised me to shrink the database. If I select Shrink in Microsoft SQL Management Studio the popup tells me that this will only remove ~400 GB, which is not to much regarding the 60% unused space of 8 TB. Why is this number so small?
4. Are there any common tricks to reduce the size which I am missing?

I searched the internet like [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186871/how-to-free-the-unused-space-for-a-table) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945388/handling-unused-disk-space-in-sql-server-db) but have not found an real answer to my question so far.

Comment: Do you have jobs to reorganize/rebuild your indexes?
Whats the fill factor of your non clustered indexes?

Comment: Seems like your indexes have PAD_INDEX set to ON with a very low FILLFACTOR.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts as far es I know there are no such jobs (I inherited the system so I am still exploring). I get new data multiple times a day coming from a spark job. I looked up the fill factor for the non-clustered indexes according to this [link]  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/specify-fill-factor-for-an-index?view=sql-server-ver15#to-specify-a-fill-factor-by-using-table-designer). It is set to 0. Could there be some sort of global fillfactor?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning While the Fill factor is set to 0, Pad index is set to *False*. Should the Fill factor be increased?

Comment: FillFactor = 0 means default = 100. Things you can check, do you have duplicate or borderline duplicate indexes (you can use [sp_blitzIndex](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit)) second you can enable [index maintenance](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html).

Comment: Are you sure it is the non-clustered indexes - and not heaps?  If your table is a heap (no clustered index) and you delete then add data constantly - space is allocated to the table and never released or reused.  If this really is a non-clustered index - have you included in those indexes an LOB data type?

Comment: The regarding table has a clustered index and two non-clustered indexes. According to the *Disk Usage by Partition* report, both the non-clustered indices have a lot more space reserved then used (about 1 to 3 each) while the clustered indexes has about the same amount reserved as used.
The database constantly gets new data, but no data is removed from it (basically log files). The data types of the non-clustered indices are *date*, *bigint* and *nvarchar*. So I guess they are LOBs. Is this the root of the problem?